# Change what Twitter Typeahead returns

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

Is it possible to change what Typeahead from Twitter returns?

So that users can search the name in the textfield, but it returns the ID that corresponds to the selected result?

I haven't been able to find anything about this, I even searched the source code.

Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modules = getBloodhound('modules');

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'id',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: modules
    });
});

var getBloodhound = function(name){
    return new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/json/' + name + '/%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you include `js` tried at Question?

Comment: See if this helps https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/0qzabbnt/

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

If interpret Question correctly, the returned array contains objects which have `name` and `id` properties. Requirement is to set the `hint` displayed at `input` element to `id` of returned object, not `name`, which would be rendered in suggestion results?

You can use `templates`, `suggestion` function to set `.tt-hint` `input`, which displays `hint` to `id` of value; set `.tt-hint` `placeholder` attribute, which displays `hint` to `id` of object argument at `suggestion` option.

Use `typeahead:render` , `input` events to set `css` `left` property of `.tt-hint`, or `placeholder` to empty string if no `value` at `.typeahead`

```
var getBloodhound = function(name){
      return new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace("value"),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/json/' + name + '/%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
      });
}

var modules = getBloodhound('modules').ttAdapter();

$(".typeahead").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true
  }, {
    name: "id",
    display: "value",
    source: modules,
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(data) {
        return "<li>" + data.team + "</li>"
      }
    }
  })
  .on("typeahead:render", function(e, data) {
    console.log(e, data);
    $(".tt-hint").attr("placeholder", data.id)
    .css("left", e.target.value.length * 10)
  })
  .on("input", function() {
    if (this.value === "" || /^\s+$/.test(this.value)) {
      $(".tt-hint").attr("placeholder", "")
    }
  })
```

```js
var nflTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("team"),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: [{
    "team": "San Francisco 49ers",
    "id": "49ers"
  }, {
    "team": "Chicago Bears",
    "id": "Bears"
  }, {
    "team": "Cincinnati Bengals",
    "id": "Bengals"
  }, {
    "team": "Buffalo Bills",
    "id": "Bills"
  }, {
    "team": "Denver Broncos",
    "id": "Broncos"
  }, {
    "team": "Cleveland Browns",
    "id": "Browns"
  }, {
    "team": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
    "id": "Buccaneers"
  }, {
    "team": "Arizona Cardinals",
    "id": "Cardinals"
  }, {
    "team": "San Diego Chargers",
    "id": "Chargers"
  }, {
    "team": "Kansas City Chiefs",
    "id": "Chiefs"
  }, {
    "team": "Indianapolis Colts",
    "id": "Colts"
  }, {
    "team": "Dallas Cowboys",
    "id": "Cowboys"
  }, {
    "team": "Miami Dolphins",
    "id": "Dolphins"
  }, {
    "team": "Philadelphia Eagles",
    "id": "Eagles"
  }, {
    "team": "Atlanta Falcons",
    "id": "Falcons"
  }, {
    "team": "New York Giants",
    "id": "Giants"
  }, {
    "team": "Jacksonville Jaguars",
    "id": "Jaguars"
  }, {
    "team": "New York Jets",
    "id": "Jets"
  }, {
    "team": "Detroit Lions",
    "id": "Lions"
  }, {
    "team": "Green Bay Packers",
    "id": "Packers"
  }, {
    "team": "Carolina Panthers",
    "id": "Panthers"
  }, {
    "team": "New England Patriots",
    "id": "Patriots"
  }, {
    "team": "Oakland Raiders",
    "id": "Raiders"
  }, {
    "team": "St.Louis Rams",
    "id": "Rams"
  }, {
    "team": "Baltimore Ravens",
    "id": "Ravens"
  }, {
    "team": "Washington Redskins",
    "id": "Redskins"
  }, {
    "team": "New Orlean Saints",
    "id": "Saints"
  }, {
    "team": "Seattle Seahawks",
    "id": "Seahawks"
  }, {
    "team": "Pittsburgh Steelers",
    "id": "Steelers"
  }, {
    "team": "Houston Texans",
    "id": "Texans"
  }, {
    "team": "Tennesse Titans",
    "id": "Titans"
  }, {
    "team": "Minnesota Vikings",
    "id": "Vikings"
  }]
})

var adapter = nflTeams.ttAdapter();

$("#default-suggestions .typeahead").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true
  }, {
    name: "nfl-teams",
    display: "value",
    source: adapter,
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(data) {
        return "<li>" + data.team + "</li>"
      }
    }
  })
  .on("typeahead:render", function(e, data) {
    console.log(e, data);
    $(".tt-hint").attr("placeholder", data.id)
    .css("left", "calc(" + e.target.value.length * 7 + "px)")
  })
  .on("input", function() {
    if (this.value === "" || /^\s+$/.test(this.value)) {
      $(".tt-hint").attr("placeholder", "")
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<div id="default-suggestions">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="NFL Teams">
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I added a console.log in the function, which does output the correct information, but it doesn't give any suggestions anymore, just a blank list. Maybe a different key instead of 'value'?

Comment: And to elaborate, I would like it to show the `name` key that is returned in the JSON, but submit the `id` key, is that possible?

Comment: @NathanPrins You should be able to substitute `return {value:results.name}` for `return {value:results.ID}`

Comment: But still, the problem remains that when I add a filter or transform it doesn't give me the suggestions in the input field anymore, it's just a blank list..

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help and effort, it is working now! :)